# Hide shipping method in woocommerce if custom checkbox field is selected

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

So, i'm trying to hide a shipping method when a custom checkout checkbox field is checked.
The custom checkbox field is "**enabledropshipping**" and the custom shipping method i need to hide is "**shipping_method_0_flat_rate1**".

```
function conditionaly_hide_shipping_method( $available_methods ) {
$post_data = urldecode($_POST['post_data']);
$post_data_arr = is_string($post_data) ? explode("&", $post_data) : array();
$field_value= '';
foreach ($post_data_arr as $value) {
$value_arr = is_string($value) ? explode("=", $value) : array();
if(isset($value_arr[0]) && $value_arr[0] === 'enabledropshipping'){
$field_value = isset($value_arr[1]) ? $value_arr[1] : '';
}
}
if(is_array($available_methods) && $field_value === 'shipping_method_0_flat_rate1'){
unset( $available_methods['shipping_method_0_flat_rate1'] );
}
return $available_methods;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_methods', 'conditionaly_hide_shipping_method' , 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Since the form is ajax i would suggest doing it the ajax way. Here is example how to trigger event and function - https://gist.github.com/heldervilela/4d1fac4d7e9c1cbf7af56656a1f0db8b